# It's possible to have a View behind a TableRow

Tags: android-layout

It's possible to have a view behind a TableRow in a TableLayout ? What I'm trying to do is at the swipe effect of the TableRow to be able to show another view in the right of it.

Comment: I don't think you can. Each child of the TableLayout is treated as a separate row, and each child of the row is treated as a separate cell in the row. If you didn't need it to be a TableLayout, then you could have each row be a FrameLayout with your main contents on top of the underneath-view. But a TableLayout is pretty restrictive.

Comment: Put it as an answer. I will mark it as `question eligible for bounty`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can. Each child of the TableLayout is treated as a separate row, and each child of the row is treated as a separate cell in the row. If you didn't need it to be a TableLayout, then you could have each row be a FrameLayout with your main contents on top of the underneath-view. But a TableLayout is pretty restrictive.